# move_uploaded_file(): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in

Tags: php, json, ajax

Uploaing multiple image via Ajax. I am using fd,.append() to send image but when i am reciving on another page then it's throwing error : move_uploaded_file(upload_documents/2017-10-04-04:41:39-aa - Copy - Copy.html): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in

[image]

so how can i slove this error please help..

HTML Code :-

```
 <input type="file" class="form-control" name="txtBusinessImageName[]" multiple id="txtDocuName" >

     <label>Select Parent</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="txtParentDocFolder">
            <option value="0">--none--</option>
    </select>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right btnUploadDocClick" >Upload</button>
```

Ajax Code :-

```
<script>

$(".btnUploadDocClick").on("click",function(e){

    var total_img=$("#txtDocuName").get(0).files.length;
    if(total_img==0){
        alert("Pleas select an image");
    }
    else{
        alert(total_img);       
         for(var i=0; i<=total_img-1; i++){
             var f_name=$("#txtDocuName").get(0).files.item(i).name;
             var f_size=$("#txtDocuName").get(0).files.item(i).size;
            console.log(f_name);
            console.log(f_size);
         }       
            var fd = new FormData();
            var file_data = $("#txtDocuName")[0].files;

            var selfolder=$("#txtParentDocFolder option:selected").val();

            fd.append("file0", file_data.length+1);

            for(var i = 0;i<file_data.length;i++){
                fd.append("file"+(i+1), file_data[i]);                          
            }
            fd.append("parent_name", selfolder);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'upload_files_page.php',
                data: fd,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST', async : true,
                success: function(data){
                    //alert("Sucessfully Saved");
                    //fetch_product_image();
                }
            }); 
      }; 
});
</script>
```

PHP Code :-

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['login'])){
        include("root/db_connection.php");
        $userID=str_replace("'","",$_SESSION['login']);
        $parent_name=str_replace("'","",$_REQUEST['parent_name']);

        $total=$_REQUEST['file0'];
         for($i=1; $i<$total; $i++)
         {
             $ctrl_id="file".$i;
             $file_name=$_FILES[$ctrl_id]['name'];

             $tmp_file_name= $file_name;

             $file_ext=pathinfo($tmp_file_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

             $a1_file=str_replace(".".$file_ext,"",$tmp_file_name);


             $currentDate=date("Y-m-d-h:i:s");
             $orignal_file_name=$currentDate."-".$a1_file;
             $orignal_file_name=$orignal_file_name.".".$file_ext;


             $insQ=$db->query("insert into user_document(file_name,file_tmp_name,folder_id,created_by,created_on) values('$orignal_file_name','$file_name',$parent_name,$userID,now())") or die("");

             if($insQ==TRUE){
                 move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$ctrl_id]['tmp_name'],"upload_documents/".$orignal_file_name);

                 echo "Sucessfully Inserted !...";
             }
             else{
                 echo "0";
             }
         }  
    }
    else{
        echo "0";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for inserting image to local directory.. It works for me. Its easy and challenging code for inserting the image path to DB and image to your local directory. Hope this will work better for you.

```
$targetfolder = !empty(@$_FILES['file']['name']) ? $targetfolder . basename( @$_FILES['file']['name']) : false;         
$file_name="your-domain/images/".@$_FILES['file']['name'];
if(move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetfolder))
 {
Code for Insert the value here in DB as path= $file_name
        }else
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Problem Uploading File!')</script>";
    }
```